# Ubuntu wifi doesnt work

Tags: networking, wireless

I can't use my wifi as when I click enable wifi it stays disabled.

Here's all the info you might need to help me
http://pastebin.com/ehLDwDzW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a module that should not be there

```
echo "blacklist acer_wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot and check `rfkill list all` if it still shows the soft block then `rfkill unblock all`

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless is soft-blocked. I assume the wireless switch or key combinaton is not working. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" > /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and let us know if it's working.

Comment: Wouldn't a wireless switch cause a hard block?

Comment: Didn't work after reboot

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless interface is soft blocked.

Try `sudo rfkill unblock wlan0`

Comment: `ruidias@ruidias-X450JF:~$ sudo rfkill list all
[sudo] password for ruidias: 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
ruidias@ruidias-X450JF:~$ sudo rfkill unblock wlan0
Bogus unblock argument 'wlan0'.
ruidias@ruidias-X450JF:~$`

Comment: `2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
`
when I do sudo rfkill unblock 2 it remains softblocked